# using tryCatch in a loop for bnets

Tags: r, try-catch

I am trying to use tryCatch to loop through a function that I know will generate errors but I cannot get the syntax right for the error.

```
xcount <- 1
while(xcount < 11){
xvar <- as.character(x[,xcount])
yvar <- as.character(x[,xcount+1])
bn <- set.arc(bn, xvar, yvar)
for(bn in 1:11){
tryCatch({
plot(bn)
score(bn, foo)
error= function(e)
print('error')})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tryCatch` syntax is off.  Use this instead:

```
tryCatch({
    print(bn)
}, error = function(e) {
    print('error')
})
```

Here is a [great reference](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912) showing how to use `tryCatch` in R.